# onSubmit Alert and Return False using inline JS

Tags: javascript, inline

I would like to add some inline javascript that alerts the user with a message AND then returns false, preventing the form from submitting.

```
onsubmit="return alert('You must be logged in to register'); return false"
```

With the code above, I get the alert but the form still submits. I would like to retain the inline JS if possible. I searched around but couldn't find an inline example that follows this pattern. I know how to achieve this by executing a function with onsubmit, but again, would like to retain inline if possible.

Comment: Why are you using `return alert()` and not `alert()`? Right now, you are returning two values, meaning that the second one won't ever get returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
<form onsubmit=" alert('You must be logged in to register');return false;"><input type="submit" /></form>
```

"Return" stops the stack instruction.

Answer (score 2):

You can not return twice from one function. Get rid of first return and it'll work as charm

Comment: Thank you! That definitely fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

by jquery you can do this:

```
$("#inputID").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  ...do whatever you want...

});
```